# BeautifulSoup if not find return 0 instead of None

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following Python syntax using BeautifulSoup for web scraping.

```
page = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'h-text-lg'})
```

For one particular page, this does not return anything because no class exists. Instead of having `None` as the returned value, how should I modify the code so it returns `[0]` instead of `None`?

Comment: If you are asking how assign `[0]` to `page` in the event that `soup.find` returns `None`, you could do `page = soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "h-text-lg"}) or [0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want it to return `None` if the class doesn't exist, you can simply change it if the value is not a truthy value

In other words:

```py
page = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'h-text-lg'}) or [0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that Python's boolean expressions return the last evaluated value:

```
page = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'h-text-lg'}) or [0]
```

**But why?** Having `None` is so much better in this case.

If `page` is the found element or `None`, any code that relies on `page` can simply check `if page` or `if not page`. This will not work if `page` is `[0]` because `bool([0])` is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` statement:

```
page = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'h-text-lg'})

if not page:
    page = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`page = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'h-text-lg'}) or [0]`

```
    def find(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None,
             **kwargs):
        """Look in the children of this PageElement and find the first
        PageElement that matches the given criteria.

        All find_* methods take a common set of arguments. See the online
        documentation for detailed explanations.

        :param name: A filter on tag name.
        :param attrs: A dictionary of filters on attribute values.
        :param recursive: If this is True, find() will perform a
            recursive search of this PageElement's children. Otherwise,
            only the direct children will be considered.
        :param limit: Stop looking after finding this many results.
        :kwargs: A dictionary of filters on attribute values.
        :return: A PageElement.
        :rtype: bs4.element.Tag | bs4.element.NavigableString
        """
        r = None
        l = self.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, text, 1, **kwargs)
        if l:
            r = l[0]
        return r
```

This is how the find method is defined , so you have to actually explicitly handle the `None` case. Hope this answers the question